# How to display a "Please wait nessage in the output" of Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app. Based  on the uiInputs I need to compute a table and display it. Since the computation is taking a while I would like to display a "Please wait" while the computation is ongoing. COuld you suggest how this could be done?

The output panel is blank when computations is done as below[image]

After the computation a table is displayed
[image]

Please let me know how I can include a "Please wait..." in output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such cases you can use [shinycssloaders](https://github.com/daattali/shinycssloaders). It is simple to apply around any output.

Here's a simple application from it's help page :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("go", "Go"),
    shinycssloaders::withSpinner(
        plotOutput("plot")
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        input$go
        Sys.sleep(1.5)
        plot(runif(10))
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Awesome! Works nicely! Thanks!!!! Wondering if it is possible to also add a message, in addition to spinner "Please wait..."

Comment: Not a straight forward one but you can try this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043297/create-loading-messages-that-will-change-based-on-loading-time-of-plot-in-a-shin

Comment: thanks. I was hoping to have the spinner and some text, but not just the text. I will keep the spinner solution. Thanks a lot!